# reading large csv files in a rails app takes up a lot of memory - Strategy to reduce memory consumption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a rails app which allows users to upload csv files and schedule the reading of  multiple csv files with help of delayed_job gem. The problem is the app reads each file in its entirity into memory and then writes to the database. If its just 1 file being read its fine, but when multiple files are read the RAM on the server gets full and causes the app to hang.

I am trying to find a solution for this problem.

One solution I researched is to break the csv file into smaller parts and save them on the server, and read the smaller files. see this [link](https://kb.iu.edu/data/afar.html)

```
 example: split -b 40k myfile segment
```

Not my preferred solution. Are there any other approaches to solve this where I dont have to break the file. Solutions must be ruby code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [`CSV.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) to read just chunks of your CSV file:

```
 path = Rails.root.join('data/uploads/.../upload.csv') # or, whatever
 CSV.foreach(path) do |row|
   # process row[i] here
 end
```

If it's run in a background job, you could additionally call [`GC.start`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/GC.html#method-c-start) every *n* rows.

---

### How it works

`CSV.foreach` operates on an IO stream, as you can see here:

```
def IO.foreach(path, options = Hash.new, &block)
  # ...
  open(path, options) do |csv|
    csv.each(&block)
  end
end
```

The `csv.each` part is a call to [IO#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-each), which reads the file line by line (`rb_io_getline_1` invokation) and leaves the line read to be garbage collected:

```c
static VALUE
rb_io_each_line(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE io)
{
    // ...
    while (!NIL_P(str = rb_io_getline_1(rs, limit, io))) {
        rb_yield(str);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Here is a great link in addition to the answer:
http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/theFullyUpturnedBin.html

Comment: Yeah, a shame that many details are outdated now. The general advice (*“[The] most common abuse […] is […] hanging on to data”*) still holds true, though.